# unicode utf-16 surrogate pair print problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

In Visual Studio /C++  declared a wstring c and filled it with a surrogate pair ( Unicode 0001F01C = Mahong tile )

```
std::cout << std::hex << 16;                    
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
std::wstring c = L"\U0001F01C";             
wchar_t* ctest = &c[0];
std::cout << "Checking value: " << *ctest << ".." <<  endl;
```

When I print out the value I would expect to get back this Unicode Number . But instead I get **d83c**.

Can anyone tell me why I don`t get the Unicode Value?

```
10Hello World!
Checking value: d83c..
```

Comment: Because you are only printing the first half of the surrogate pair? And I guess VS's implementation decides to print this in hex.

Comment: How do I get the unicode value then?

Comment: you could decode the UTF-16 data stored in the string. Note that Windows uses UTF-16 but other OSes might use UTF-32 in which case there is no decoding.

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: Yes I know that it is composed but how do I get to print out the value 0001F01C. Can someone give me a piece of code please? thanks

Comment: sorry eljay, this gives me 3c000

Comment: A surrogate pair is a pair of UTF-16 encoding units that have to be recombined in your code to extract the Unicode code point value. `(static_cast<std::uint32_t>(ctest[0] & 0x03FF) << 10) | (ctest[1] & 0x03FF) | 0x10000U`  ... I don't usually deal with UTF-16, I'm a UTF-8 everywhere advocate.

Comment: ...still 3c000 ...

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35550615/4641116

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do the reverse operation that creates a UTF-16 surrogate pair.

**U+10000 to U+10FFFF**

0x010000 is subtracted from the code point, leaving a 20-bit number in the range 0..0x0FFFFF.

The top ten bits (a number in the range 0..0x03FF) are added to 0xD800 to give the first 16-bit code unit or high surrogate, which will be in the range 0xD800..0xDBFF.

The low ten bits (also in the range 0..0x03FF) are added to 0xDC00 to give the second 16-bit code unit or low surrogate, which will be in the range 0xDC00..0xDFFF.

To reconstitute the surrogate pair into a Unicode code point, just do the opposite:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::hex << 16 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::u16string c = u"\U0001F01C";
    char16_t* ctest = &c[0];
    std::cout << "Checking value: " << *ctest << ".." <<  "\n";
    std::cout << "Checking value: " << ((static_cast<std::uint32_t>(ctest[0] & 0x03FF) << 10) | (ctest[1] & 0x03FF) | 0x10000U) << ".." <<  "\n";
}
```