# Can Windows' std::wcout display UTF-16 wchar_t surrogate pairs as a unicode character?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, utf-16, wchar-t, surrogate-pairs

[[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fvnPa93E8)]

```
\U0001F34C\U0002008A on cout  : 
\U0001F34C\U0002008A on wcout : 
                      wcsnlen : 4
1 :     0xd83c
2 :     0xdf4c
3 :     0xd840
4 :     0xdc8a
    wcsrtombs to char on cout :
```

Even though UCRT makes MSVC more compliant with the standard.

Each character above BMP on Windows is stored as a UTF-16 [surrogate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68893235/6370128). It looks like standard `std::wcout` on Windows is implemented in the way it can't display any of these characters.

Other than convert back from `wchar_t` to multibyte `char` (UTF-8), can we make Windows `std::wcout` display these kind of characters right away?

Comment: If you want to output `UTF-16` you need to set the terminal to `UTF-16` so it understands what you are outputting.

Comment: @Galik Could you remind us how to do that please, I can never remember.  Thx.  But, OP, surrogate pairs are nothing special in this regard, although not all code points are displayable in all fonts.

Comment: @PaulSanders How you do that will depend on the terminal you are using. On the terminal I use most, I have a drop-down menu to select which encoding I want it to display.

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328697/using-utf-16-for-i-o-with-visual-studio-instead-of-code-pages

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks. Well, unfortunately `WriteConsoleW` seems to be only API to work with `wchar_t` string directly, not the standard `std::wcout`.